# How to show the values in text fields to edit when loading the page in c# mvc?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using asp.net c# with entity framework code first. So here i've created a user profile and i need to show the values as editable when page is loading. So i have passed the email as below.

```
public ActionResult Manage()
    {
        //LoadData();
        var manageviewmodel = new ManageViewModel() { Email = Session["UserEmail"].ToString()};
        return View(manageviewmodel);
    }
```

But i want to get the other fields also as editable fields. So for that i have used the following way to get Firstname to the editable field.

```
public ActionResult Manage()
    {
        //LoadData();
        var manageviewmodel = new ManageViewModel() { Email = Session["UserEmail"].ToString(),FirstName = Session["Fname"].ToString() };
        return View(manageviewmodel);
    }
```

But it is not worked for me. Is there any suggessions?

Comment: What is not working exactly? and which way are you using to authenticate your users? using asp.net identity or what?

Comment: I have used entity framework but not identity.

Comment: You should not reinvent the wheel, use Asp.Net Identity to authenticate your users, and in case it is it not feasible, then load the user object using the `Session["UserEmail"]` variable and retrieve any properties you need from it, you can also store the whole object in session